# how do I call a spring mvc REST controller from angular.js?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

**How do I hook up an angularjs web form with a spring mvc REST controller, so that only a small fragment of a page is refreshed (instead of the entire page) when the form is submitted?**

In this case, only a string is refreshed in the page instead of refreshing the entire page.  Specifically, **how do I alter the code below so that the only element on the page that refreshes from the server after form submit is `<H1>${person.answer}</H1>`.**

**NOTE:  the code below has been edited to adhere to @Cotta's suggestions.  I am replacing the original code with @Cotta's suggestions instead of appending because I want this to be easy to read.**

`index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- CSS ===================== -->
    <!-- load bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <style>
        body    { padding-top:30px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS ===================== -->
    <!-- load angular -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply angular app and controller to our body -->
<body ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header"><h1>What is your name?</h1></div>

    <!-- FORM -->
    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate> <!-- novalidate prevents HTML5 validation since we will be validating ourselves -->

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" required>
        </div>

        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>

</div><!-- col-sm-8 -->
</div><!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
<!-- example from: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation -->
```

`app.js` is:

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['ngResource']);

validationApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope'], '$resource', function($scope, $resource) { 
  // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
  $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

    // check if form is valid before sending data to the server
    if (isValid) {
        var NameCheck = $resource('/api/namecheck', {});
        var result = NameCheck.get();
        console.log(result.answer);
    }

  };

});
```

`RingRestController.java` is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RingRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/namecheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Person create(@RequestBody Person person) {
        String answer = "";
        if (person.getName().equals("Frodo") || person.getName().equals("frodo")){
            answer = "Frodo, would you please hold onto this ring for me?";
        }
        else {
            answer = "Thank you for telling us your name.";
        }
        person.setTransientAnswer(answer);
        return person;
    }

}
```

**NOTE:  this uses the same core project as the angularjs branch of the spring petclinic sample app (I deleted everything in `/src/main/webapp` and built up new angularjs within the spring project shell.  Thus, it uses the same spring.xml config files, which might be related to a solution.  You can read the spring config files [by clicking on this link](https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/resources/spring).**

Comment: use `$http` to make ajax request, see docs for particulars

Comment: @charlietfl google generates a bunch of incomplete answers that do not work out of the box.  Or google generates fully featured sample apps way beyond the scope of this question.  I just want a simple working solution to this question so that I can build up my own app from pieces that I understand instead of relying on a pre-built app.  Are you willing to elaborate about this specific question?

Comment: as mentioned, start with the docs  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http There are lots of basic ajax tutorials around. You need to create your data object from your model object and send that to server with `$http`

Comment: I read all day long and only ask questions when I hit a dead end.  I am hoping that someone can answer this question on the level on which it is asked.  Thank you.

Comment: but it is asked for us to code it for you which is too broad. This isn't a coding service. The `$http` part is quite simple...and you need a script at server to receive the data the same way you would a form

Comment: I am not asking for it to be coded for me.  I am asking for the code I have already written to be appended as a working answer.  People will google this for years to come looking for working code.  These comments are merely for a potential answerer to scope out an answer on the level on which the question was asked.

Comment: Color it any way you want. I gave you the basics and maybe someone will code it for you but I doubt it

Comment: Quit posting all these chatterring off-topic comments.  Comments are to elucidate an answer, not to engage in extraneous conversations.

Comment: maybe you should have done that search yourself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204725/separation-of-spring-mcv-rest-and-angular-js-single-page-architecture?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this by:

1. Include `ngResource` in your application

   ```
   var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['ngResource']);
   ```
2. Inject `$resource` on your controller

   ```
   validationApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) { ... }]);
   ```
3. Then you may use `$resource` to create an object responsible for sending your requests inside `submitForm`:

   ```
   var NameCheck = $resource('http://url-to-service', {});
   var result = NameCheck.get();
   console.log(result.answer);
   ```
4. Remember to include angular-resource.js file.

You may also do something similiar with `$http` and a few lines of code more.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  This is Spring MVC, so there is no `http://url-to-service`.  Instead, the REST call would go to `/namecheck`, as shown in the controller code in my OP.  Are you willing to show how your suggestions would fit into the specific code I wrote in my OP?  I am currently researching `$http`, but I am open to your approach if you can show that it works.

Comment: All this are changes to your `app.js` file: #1 and #2 are simple replacements to the first two lines of code (excluding comments), #3 will be placed after the `if (isValid) {` line and `angular-resource.js` must be declared on a `<script>` tag inside your page.

Comment: I made all of your changes, and then posted them to my OP to replace my previous code.  The code does not connect to the server yet.  I also added a link to the spring.xml config files at the end of my OP.  What else can you suggest?

Comment: This link might contain a clue leading to an answer: https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/components/_partials/SearchController.js

Comment: So this may not be an AngularJS question, but something broader. Did you check if the request is at least being fired by your client side code (eg.: on Google Chrome network tab after hitting F12 key)?